# What is a "double zero" when I am trying to factor a quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A writing quadratic equations problem has a double zero of -1.  I need to use this to find my two zeros and for a standard form equation.

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as a "repeated root". By the factor theorem, a single root at $x=a$ means that the polynomial has $(x-a)$ as a factor. In your case you know that $(x-a)^2$ is a factor.

Comment: Thanks you! That worked. If you  like you can post an answer and I'll resolve it for you so you get more reps.

Comment: Thanks, but there are some other good answers already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a **very nice relationship** between the zeros of a polynomial and the factors of a polynomial.

If we have a polynomial, and you know, for example, that $2$ is a zero, then $(x - 2)$ is a factor of that polynomial!  That means if you were to factor the polynomial completely, you would see $(x-2)$ somewhere in there.  Similarly, if $-1$ were a zero, then $(x - (-1))$ would be a factor.  If $c$ is a zero, the factor is always $(x - c)$.

That's really great news, because that means if you have a really big polynomial which seems way too hard to factor, you can use the polynomial long division to break it down.

Now, if we know that there is a **double** zero, like in your case $-1$, that means not only is $(x - (-1))$ a factor [which, if you simplify, equals $(x + 1)$].  But actually, since $-1$ is a **double** zero, then $(x - (-1))^{2}$ is a factor of the polynomial.

So $(x - (-1))^{2}$, which equals $(x + 1)^{2}$, is a factor.

So multiply this out and get $x^{2} + 2x + 1$.  Now use polynomial long division to divide this into your original polynomial to get the other factors.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Solving_polynomial_equations):

> Every polynomial $P$ in $x$ corresponds to a function, $f(x)=P$ (where the occurrences of $x$ in $P$ are interpreted as the argument of $f$), called the *polynomial function* of $P$; the equation in $x$ setting $f(x)=0$ is the *polynomial equation* corresponding to $P$. The solutions of this equation are called the *roots* of the polynomial; they are the *zeroes* of the function $f$ (corresponding to the points where the graph of $f$ meets the $x$-axis). A number $a$ is a root of $P$ if and only if the polynomial $x−a$ (of degree one in $x$) divides $P$. It may happen that $x−a$ divides $P$ more than once: if $(x−a)^2$ divides $P$ then $a$ is called a *multiple root* of $P$, and otherwise $a$ is called a *simple root* of $P$.